# Permutations on the leading diagonal of a matrix

Tags: combinatorics

I have an $n\times n$ matrix with only diagonal components which are $\pm 1$. How many of these matrices can I construct? I know this is a basic combinatorics, but I would appreciate some help figuring it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look for the number $F_n$ of functions from $\{ 1,2,...,n\}$ to $\{1,-1\}$. There are
$$ F_n =| \{ 1 , -1 \} |^{|\{ 1,...,n  \}|} = 2^n $$
such functions.

Think of this: for the 1st entry $a_{1,1}$ you have 2 options, for the second entry $a_{2,2}$ there are again 2 options. So in total there are now $2 \times 2 = 2^2$ options. Let us list them all: 
$$ (+1,+1), \quad (+1,-1) , \quad (-1,+1), \quad (-1,-1) \ .$$
By induction you can show that $F_n = 2 F_{n-1}$ (with $F_1 = 2$) and thus $F_n = 2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this problem in terms of how many options you have for each matrix entry. Let $P_{ij}$ denote the number of allowed entries for the $i,j$ entry of the matrix. How can you combine these numbers to get the total number of matrices satisfying your condition?

Alternately, you could prove this by induction on $n$.